# Vimeo iframe in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, embed, vimeo

how is it possible to view a video from vimeo embed code in a webview in android?
I only hear the audio but the video stays black.

```
                wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(wb.getUrl(),
                    "<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/**********?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                    "text/html",
                    "utf-8",
                    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

way too late to the party here,
i didnt  use  i did it like this and it works for me.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/video/" +"insert video id here"+ "?player_id=player&autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&api=1&maxheight=680&maxwidth=1000");
```

and change width and height according to your needs